# PDFKit Borders showing even thou there are not set

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

I'm trying to generate a PDF from some html and css. I'm using PDFKit and Rails to generate it.

It works but when i use border-left,border-right,border-top or border-bottom it will also draw a small half-transparent line on the other borders even if all the other borders are set to none.

Example:

[image]

Are there any way to hide the other borders that are not ment to be visable?